Bitwise operation for all elements of a vector
For a Vec<u32> of undefined size, what is the Rust way of calling a bitwise (and, or, xor, etc.) operator on all of them, and returning with the resulting data?
I understand it is possible with a simple loop, what I'm looking for is the Rust way™.

You can use Iterator::fold. For example with bitwise or, |:
pub fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 4, 8];

    let sum = a.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| acc | x);

    assert_eq!(sum, 15);
}

(Example taken from https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#examples-38 and adjusted.)

You can also use Iterator::reduce, which will use the first element as the initial value, and returns an Option<T>.

@AleksanderKrauze Reading the note in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold ("reduce() can be used...") I just tried it and found it didn't compile in the first 2 attempts ;) feel free to add an answer showing how to use it correctly.

@mkrieger1 https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78caf80da5df1ef2d6afdaa30d796fcf reduce needs the "accumulator" and the iterator values to have the same type since the initial value of the accumulator is one of the iterator values.

@mkrieger1 it depends on what exactly you want to do with this iterator. As @Masklinn said, reduce can be used, if function you pass to it has signature FnMut(T, T) -> T. Where T = Iterator::Item.
